# C: error: incompatible pointer types, remove & - a pointer to store its own address

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

Beginner question: I think I understand pointers(int *p, x = 1, p = &x) somewhat but not when "->" and structs are involved apparently.

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;

    struct node* children[27];
}
node;
```

and

```
node* root = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

printf("address:%p\n", &root->children[1]);
printf("content%p\n", root->children[1]);

printf("\n");
root->children[1] = &root->children[1];

printf("address:%p\n", &root->children[1]);
printf("content%p\n", root->children[1]);
```

Simply, I have a pointer, I want it to store its own address. but it gives me:

```
error: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct node *'
      from 'struct node **'; remove & [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        root->children[1] = &root->children[1];
                          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried some combinations, none worked so far. What am I missing?

Comment: A `node *` points to a `node` and not to a `node *`.

Comment: The address of a variable of type `T` is type `T*`.  So you're trying to assign a `T*` to a `T`.  There is only one type capable of that in C...

Comment: "have a pointer, I want it to store its own address". Why?

Comment: This is not about structs or `->`. The following would fail to compile for the same reason: `int *p; p = &p;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you comment to Ishay's answer, you want to achieve *content == address*...

It is easy to obtain that, but I want to warn you why you should not. If `node->children[1]` point to its own address, it is undefined behaviour to dereference the pointer since what lies there is **not** a `node` but a `node *`. That means that once you have that, any access to `*(node->children[1])` be it for read or write, and even using `node->children[1]->...` syntax, is explicitely Undefined Behaviour per the strict aliasing rule (search SO for *C strict aliasing rule* for more details on that).

Once you have been warned, C language is very confident in programmer, and allows you to do even non sensical things:

```
root->children[1] = (void *) &root->children[1]; /* or root->children[1] = (node *) &root->children[1]; */

printf("address:%p\n", &root->children[1]);
printf("content%p\n", root->children[1]);
```

will display what you want. This is because it is always allowed to copy a pointer to a `(void *)`, and the same, a `void *` may be copied to any other pointer. C standard requires that (provided there are no alignement problem and there should not be in your example) those pointer assignement are perfectly defined and that:

```
node ** p = (node **) root->children[1];
```

is also defined and the `p` must point to `root->children[1]`. Said differently you may cast a pointer to one type to a pointer to another type, and casting it back shall give you the initial value but you **must not** derefence the *incorrect* pointer.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I actually knew the solution as I was reading about printing pointers(after I asked the question) I saw (void*) usage inside printf being recommended. Trying it worked. Still I waited an answer for explanation. I do not intend to use it as a pointer, it is just I didn't know what to store in it beside NULL and I thought, why not its own address. I will only use it for (!NULL) checking. I guess, it can be condensed into: A pointer may be an address but an address is not a pointer unless you say so.

Comment: @vtastek:  You should **really** just use NULL.

Comment: @vtastek: To line up with the other warnings: **Don't!** You invoke undefined behaviour and the compiler can do anything it wants. Modern compilers like gcc are very strict about standard voilations and like to exploit them when it seems better for their optimisation goal.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`root->children[1] = &root->children[1];`
to
`root->children[1] = root->children[1];`

The reason it doesn't work is exactly as stated in the error message -

`root->children[i]` is of type node*, this means that root->children[i] is itself a memory address pointing to data of type `struct node`.

That being said, why would you want to store memory addresses?
Consider the following example: You a pointer to type int:
`int *ptr`
Now, if you want the memory address for ptr, you can just `printf("%p", ptr)`
and if you want the data, just `printf("%d", *ptr)`

Comment: I thought that too.

address:0x149e260
content(nil)

Comment: root->children[i] is a pointer of type node* which means memory address. You're storing another memory address in it which (for my best understanding) is what you want to do... What is the problem?

Comment: address:0x149e260 content: 0x149e260 
This is what I am after.

Comment: Okay, I got you now. You do realize that struct node is a type? You defined it's contents as bool and anther struct pointer, how do you expect to get a pointer contents there?

Comment: It is a pointer, it is supposed to store an address. It must have an address which theoretically I should be able do store as a pointer.

Comment: That is correct indeed, but you're trying to store a memory address into the _contents_ of the pointer, not the actual address (i.e you're trying to store a memory address into the actual struct, which doesn't make sense)

Comment: But isn't it an array of pointers? The contents are supposed to be addresses. "a memory address" vs. "the actual address" . What is the difference? Like, physical vs. virtual?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but an array of pointers means you have an array of memory addresses. If you want to assign memory addresses to any element of the array that will work. What you're trying to do is assign a memory address to the actual data which is like trying to assign a long integer value into a node struct

Comment: I have to ask - why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think it is because I got the trie building the wrong way around. And I couldn't figure it out what to store in root since tails would be pointing up and I had to fill root with something! So I thought why not store its own address for the root. :D

Comment: Gotcha. It's worth rethinking your construction though... Storing the contents in a struct is a _really_ bad idea

Comment: But this is CS50. They wanted us to implement a spell checker and all they gave us was "Here is Zamyla, want to build a trie? Here is some struct code. Good luck" **That** struct code.